# Contract templates for open source work

Tags: law, contracts

Are there published templates or guidelines for contract terms for engagements where the deliverable is new open source software or an enhancement to existing open source software? I have some of my own that I've used on various projects, but I'd like to be able to compare, and have references to show to clients who may not be used to such engagements and entering into them for the first time to establish what the norms are.

I generally work from a master agreement that specifies upstream project policy (this is all on existing software) will be followed regarding assignment or non-assignment of copyright and any CLAs needed, giving unlimited license to the client to exploit and sublicense independent new code produced, and setting mutual non-interference expectation between parties (including via patents). Are there other important things I should be including? Examples I could look at (or contribute to) for improving or clarifying the wording of such terms?

I've seen the question [Standard contract for OSS work](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/8689/463) but it does not seem like a comparable situation.